# Number tags <images> XSLT / XML

Tags: xml, xslt

**XSLT 2.0** has a built-in function tokenize() for such tasks.

Below is our Input XML code for import products images.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <post>
        <SKU>I-DQ5285 53053</SKU>
        <ImageURL>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053.jpg|https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_2.jpg|https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_3.jpg|https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_4.jpg</ImageURL>
    </post>
</data>
```

Code XSLT transform

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ImageURL">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="'ImageURL'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="elemName"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="$elemName"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML. Now I paste result below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <post>
    <SKU>I-DQ5285 53053</SKU>
    <ImageURL>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053.jpg</ImageURL>
    <ImageURL>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_2.jpg</ImageURL>
    <ImageURL>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_3.jpg</ImageURL>
    <ImageURL>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_4.jpg</ImageURL>
  </post>
</data>
```

Except result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <post>
    <SKU>I-DQ5285 53053</SKU>
    <ImageURL1>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053.jpg</ImageURL1>
    <ImageURL2>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_2.jpg</ImageURL2>
    <ImageURL3>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_3.jpg</ImageURL3>
    <ImageURL4>https://testweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/DQ5285-53053_4.jpg</ImageURL4>
  </post>
</data>
```

Can anyone help us to automatically number this one? We will appreciate your help.

Comment: Which processor are you using? Some XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="elemName"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <xsl:element name="{$elemName}{$i}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="$elemName"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: With this above I get issue: https://prnt.sc/1xv5w8c

Comment: Line 37 php code is :         $xslDoc = new \DOMDocument();
        $xslDoc->loadXML($xsl, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

Comment: I am afraid I have no clue what you describe. You can see the code working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA2e